# How can I add external libraries to a cmake install?

Tags: cmake, installation

My cmake project builds against external libraries, e.g. Boost. I would now like to advise cmake to generate "make install code" that causes all used external libraries to be added to the installation package.

My hope is that cmake can inspect the built shared objects and executables, e.g. using ldd, to find out which external libraries are required and add them without explicit naming of the individual libraries in the CMakeLists.txt.

Of course there is the other case in which the built code expicitly loads the external libaries (dlopen(), ...), e.g. as done by Intel IPP. In this case I would probably somehow need to explicitly name the libraries to install, e.g. using some variables set by the FindXXX cmake scripts.

Comment: `cmake can inspect the built shared objects and executables, e.g. using ldd, to find out which external libraries are required and add them without explicit naming` - Among these libraries will be `libc` or `libstdc++` library, but you don't want to install it, do you? Probably, because of CMake cannot decide by itself, which library should be (re)installed and which is not, it doesn't provide such functionality - you need to list libraries for install by yourself.

Comment: If you don't want to depend on external libraries, I suggest to link them static into your binary. Installing your own copy of shared libraries is asking for trouble.

Comment: @arved "....asking for trouble.": I agree totally, but this is the way we have done it the last decade and only once had a problem. I am now trying to migrate to cmake and do not want to extend the scope of this effort too much and thereby risking it to fail.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your take on this. I would have thought that the c/c++ runtime libraries are so much part of the "platform" that one could reasonably assume that these shall not be added to the installation. Take my comment with 10**10 grains of salt: I have no experience with installers on different platforms, platform versions, ... There must be some good practices how to do this otherwise the Linux distro builders would have absolutely no chance.

Comment: I have an implementation that uses
     include (GetPrerequisites)
     get_prerequisites(${lib} dependencies 1 1 "" "")
     foreach(dep_lib ${dependencies})
        gp_resolve_item (${lib} ${dep_lib} "" "" resolved_file)

Comment: would [`install(IMPORTED_RUNTIME_ARTIFACTS ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#imported-runtime-artifacts) help with this?